# Can not set region as a relocation target

Tags: support, jobs

Today I created my profile on Careers, but I had problems with setting the region where I would like to relocate. I tried `Bayern`, but it turns into `Germany`.

So, is there a way to set the region? Or am I stuck with whole Germany?

Comment: Have you tried `Bavaria`?

Comment: Ah, indeed - only city level seems to be possible in Germany, or the whole country. That is a bit... imprecise. Whereas in the US, you can enter a state.

Comment: I think the location stuff is all through Yahoo, so it's not something SE can fix

Comment: Maybe they need a different service for coding regions, then. This really is a big impediment

Answer (score 1):

We’ve made an adjustment that should improve this. Try it again?

Comment: Works for me! ---

Comment: I just tried "South of Germany", and it turned into "Germany" again :(